# Can Visual Studio "15" Preview be installed alongside 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio "15" was released on the 30th March.

Can [Visual Studio "15"](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs15-preview-vs) preview be safely installed along side Visual Studio 2015?

The news article doesn't seem to say one way or another and everything I hit on google only talks about 2015, not "15".

Comment: That is certainly the *idea*; I can't guarantee you a "yes, that's fine", and I don't work for Microsoft, but: I have them both installed fairly happily. Anecdotal, not official ;p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@NikolaiDante, yes you can install Visual Studio "15" Preview alongside Visual Studio 2015. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio "15" preview and both are working fine.

[image]

Even though you can see in the screenshot That I am Using 4 Versions of Visual Studio **(Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015, and Visual Studio "15") and all 4 version are working fine.**